# Bash getops: allow, but not require arg

Tags: bash, options, parsing

I'm writing a bash script, parsing options with getopts like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    while getopts ab: ; do
        case $opt in
          a) AOPT=1
             ;;
          b) BOPT=$OPTARG
             ;;
        esac
    done
```

I'd like to have the "-b" option OPTIONALLY take an argument, but as it is, getopts complains if no argument is passed. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: it would be courteous of you to go back and "accept" answers to your previous questions where appropriate. Looks like you've accepted none of them so far. It's just a way to give back to the SF community. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, sorry - I hadn't quite gotten the hang of the system yet.

Comment: No problem, Frank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run getopts in silent mode by including a colon as the first character of the optstring.  This can be used to suppress the error message.

From the getopts manpage:

```
If the first character of optstring is a colon, the  shell  variable specified  
by name shall be set to the colon character and the shell variable OPTARG shall 
be set to the option character found.
```

Thus something like the following might work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

AOPT="unassigned"
BOPT="unassigned"

while getopts :ab: opt ; do
  case $opt in
    a) AOPT=1
       ;;
    b) BOPT=$OPTARG
       ;;
    :) BOPT=
       ;;
  esac
done

echo "AOPT = $AOPT"
echo "BOPT = $BOPT"
```

Some examples:

```
rlduffy@hickory:~/test/getopts$ ./testgetopts -a -b Hello
AOPT = 1
BOPT = Hello
rlduffy@hickory:~/test/getopts$ ./testgetopts -b goodbye
AOPT = unassigned
BOPT = goodbye
rlduffy@hickory:~/test/getopts$ ./testgetopts -a -b
AOPT = 1
BOPT =
```